# Socket.io 1.4.5 Rooms issue

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am unable to emit events to rooms in my server application, using version 1.4.5

I tried these two ways to communicate in a room, but neither worked.

```
this.io.to(this.id).emit(eventName,data);
this.io.sockets.in(this.id).emit(eventName,data);
```

Before calling this, i register user in the room in this fashion

```
user.socket.join(this.id);
```

Further details

- the `this.io` object is `require('socket.io')(http);`
- the `user.socket` object is `io.on('connection', function(socket)`

I omitted the rest of the code because it is in overly complex structure and inheritance chain, and also irellevant to this question.

I dont necessarily require a code snippet to copy, rather a way how to debug and figure the issue out.

**EDIT**

When i pause the application at the moment when i want to emit the message, when I inspect the `io` object, i get the following.

```
io -> nsps -> '/' -> adapter -> rooms -> theRoomName -> sockets
```

And my socket id **is** listed there.

Is there a way how to find out whether the message is actually being sent ?

**EDIT #2**

When I inspect the socket object, located at

```
io -> sockets -> sockets -> "socket id" -> rooms
```

the room id **is** present there as well

Comment: The first four things to confirm are: 1) What is the value of `this.io` and is that what it is supposed to be. 2) What is the value of `this.id` and is that what it is supposed to be. 3) What is `eventName`?  4) Is the client actually listening for the `eventName` message?

Comment: You can trace into the `.emit()` function call in the debugger on the server to see if it thinks it should actually send a message and see what it does.  You can use a network trace on your server (like WireShark or Ethereral) to see if it is actually sending anything.  You can use the Network tab in the Chrome debugger to see if a message arrives on the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this. All those variables have been correctly set, i made sure before posting here. It is the fourth step that was it. During a refactor of the client i forgot to attach a listener for that event. Thanks a plenty again, if you would be able to create an answer out of this i will gladly accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer per your request:

The first four things to confirm are:

1. What is the value of `this.io` and is that what it is supposed to be?
2. What is the value of `this.id` and is that what it is supposed to be?
3. What is `eventName`?
4. Is the client actually listening for the `eventName` message?

Also, you can use the server debugger to trace into `.emit()` and see that it is actually intending to send a message.

Then, you can use a network trace on the server like WireShark or Ethereal to verify that the server is actually sending a message out.

Then, you can use the network tab in the Chrome debugger to see if a message is actually arriving to the browser page.

---

**PostScript:** It sounds like item 4 above is where the problem actually was.